# More efficient way to set variable from multiple sources?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set a variable in Javascript.  I want the variable to use one of the following.

1st choice if exists

```
$(this).attr("data-name");
```

2nd choice if above doesnt exist

```
$(this).attr("name");
```

3rd choice if neither above dont exist

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

And when I say doesnt exists I mean   not null, not undefined and not blank.

I am not sure an efficient way to do this in javascript could use a bit of help on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `||` operator:

```
var name = $(this).data('name') || this.name || this.id;
```

This says "use the `data-name` attribute; if it is falsy, use the `name` property; if it is falsy, use the `id` property."

Falsy values are:

- false
- null
- undefined
- an empty string
- the number `0`
- `NaN`

Comment: Will this also confirm those do not return null or undefined?

Comment: Thanks for the help lonesomeday, this works great and I will find this very useful going forward.